# Tantalum capacitor selection in LT3652 Buck Converter

Tags: buck, bypass-capacitor, tantalum

[image]

In this circuit, a buck solar single cell Li-Ion battery charger, I need to select C3 and C4 tantalum capacitors. \$V_{BAT(FLT)}\$ is going to be 4.2 V, hence I selected:

\$C3_{VMAX}=10\text{ V}\$
\$C4_{VMAX}=10\text{ V}\$

Datasheet suggests low ESR tantalum capacitors but the supplier has capacitors ranging from \$1\text{ }\Omega\text{ to }80\text{ }\text{m}\Omega\$.

1. Are the \$C3_{VMAX}\$ and \$C4_{VMAX}\$ values I picked, correct for this application?
2. What ESR values should I pick for the tantalum capacitors for this application, and why?

Comment: If you look at the datasheets for the suggested Sanyo OS-CON or POSCAP capacitors, you will find the ESR for those.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I thought the exact series wasn't mandatory. Anyway I found a 47 uF 10V POSCAP at 35 mOhm.

Comment: You wanted to know the acceptable ESR, so I thought that looking at capacitors with acceptable ratings would be a good guide.

Comment: It's the first time I work with tantalum capacitors, so I'm inexperienced. Do you think that the 35 mOhm cap I found should be fine?